# Xcode and Core Data - 'Create NSManagedObject Subclass'

Tags: xcode, core-data

In Xcode, I can select ONE entity and go to Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass. This bit is fine. I get the class out of ONE entity.

However....

The other day, somehow I got Xcode instead to pop up a dialog with all my entities with checkboxes next to them. I could select multiple entities all at once, which it would then create the classes for all selected.

I can't seem to find how I did this !!! Anybody use this and know how?

(Don't suggest me to use mogenerator. I know about this.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. It's ridiculous.

Select/Highlight an Entity, then highlight an attribute in that entity.... any one.....

... then go to 'Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass'.

Apparently you can also just highlight multiple entities and then do the same above, although I haven't tried this.